# save sql variable with php from select dropdown

Tags: php, sql, variables

i have the following select in my code. now it posts the whole  value to the next page, but how can i pass the variable $dagen to the next page?

```
<form method="post" action="pagina4.php?lang=<?=$_SESSION['lang'];?>&naam=<?=$naam;?>&fietskeuze=<?=$fietskeuze;?>&opties=<?=$opties;?>&optieid=<?=$optieid;?>">
        <select id="dagen" name="dagen" style="width:250px;" style="height:250px;">
            <?php
            $query="SELECT * FROM $tabel WHERE fietstype='$fietskeuze'";
            $result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Ophalen prijzen mislukt: ".mysql_error());

            while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $dagen=$row[dagen];
            $prijs=$row[prijs];
                echo "<option>
                    $dagen ".$lang['pagina3_dag']." - Tarief: EUR   ".$prijs."  
                </option>";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You already are. Some of your variables are available in `$_GET` (the query string of the action attribute), but the `dagen` variable will be available in `$_POST['dagen']`.

If the complete string is not what you want, you can add a value attribute to get just your `$dagen` variable:

```
 echo "<option value="<?php echo $dagen; ?>">
     ...
```

Comment: i already had it as $_POST but i get the whole value from between the <option tags>, and i want to pass $dagen also apart

Comment: @user2133342 Just added that. If you want to send both the value **and** the string, you might need to add a hidden form field that gets updated automatically by javascript when the select is changed. However, that should not be necessary as you can get everything from the database again. You could also parse the string, plenty of options...